# Declaring a char which takes a preprocessor macro?

Tags: c++, macros, char, int

I am using a provided API which has some macro definitions for integers as follows:

```
// Macros for logic values
#define LOGIC_UNSET -1
#define LOGIC_ZERO   0
#define LOGIC_ONE    1
#define LOGIC_D      2 
#define LOGIC_DBAR   3
#define LOGIC_X      4 

// Macros for fault types
#define NOFAULT   -1
#define FAULT_SA0 0
#define FAULT_SA1 1
```

Now, in a one of the API functions, it is declaring a variable of type `char` and is the value being assigned to this `char` is that of one of the macros.

```
bool getObjective(Gate* &g, char &v, Circuit* myCircuit)
```

Where `v` receives the value of of the `LOGIC` macros.

This doesnt make sense to me and when i was trying to do `cout` on the char, i was getting ascii symbols which didnt help me. Im really confused by this. Is this a mistake? Can you pass an `int` to a `char`? And if yes, how can i print the char so that i get the macro or macro value on the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<<` overload on `ostream` for a `char` *intentionally* prints the ASCII symbol.

You can obviate this behaviour by using `<< (int)v`.

There is nothing wrong with using a `char` to store an integral value. Although do be aware that `char` can be an `unsigned` type, so that might make the behaviour of `NOFAULT` (as `-1`) difficult to manage.

Best thing to do: use an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an `int` to `char` variable. Provided either you are ready to scarify some part of the `int` if `int` is 32bit and char is 16 bit, or your your `int` is 16bit only.

To print you can always cast,

```
std::cout<< (int) your_char
```